# CSS hyperlink style for text only links

Tags: html, css

On my website I have a global CSS rule for hyperlinks:

```
a {
    color: #1F497D;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #1F497D;
}
```

This works well for text-only hyperlinks - the link gets a background colour applied to it on hover.

```
<a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
```

However this is causing issues with other link types, for example:

```
<a href="image.png">
    <img src="thumb.png" alt="" />
</a>
```

In the above example, the image is a transparent PNG, therefore the background colour applied by the `a:hover` rule can be seen on hover.

Is there any way we can adjust the global CSS rule so that it only applies to text links? I know I can add a separate class for these links but as there are so many  I would prefer an easier solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a class to anchor tags that are not texts:

```
a.not-a-text:hover {
 background-color: transparent;
}
```

Them in the HTML:

```
<a class="not-a-text" href="image.png">
    <img src="thumb.png" alt="" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked for an "easier" solution (rather than adding classes), you could apply a style using an attribute selector (where `a` elements have an `href` attribute that end with a `png` extension) to have a `transparent` background.

Something like this:

```
a[href$=".png"]:hover{
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Here's a fiddle (has a `red` hover which you could set to `transparent`):

http://jsfiddle.net/sb6xvztm/

Answer (score 1):

Definitely digging up an old post, but in the event anyone else comes here searching for insight...

*DISCLAIMER: The `:has` selector is disabled by default on Firefox version 103. Check the compatibility before trying this yourself.*

This can be done with the [`:has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) and [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) selectors:

```
a:not(:has(> *)) {
    color: #1F497D;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

With `:has(> *)`, we are selecting items that have selectable children (not text nodes). In the context of hyperlinks this will usually mean it's a non-text-only link which contains some other elements (images in your case). By wrapping it in a `:not()` selector we select only text links.

To add hovering styles:

```
a:not(:has(> *)):hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #1F497D;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use CSS classes on the links instead of tags because it will make maintenance much easier.

```
.text-link {
    color: #1f497d;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.text-link:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #1F497D;
}

<a class="text-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
<a class="img-link"><img src="someimage.jpg" alt="alt"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not against your site running jQuery I suggest this SIMPLE solution:

```
jQuery('a').hover(function(){
    jQuery(this).has('img').css('background', 'none');
});
```

Working Example Here http://jsfiddle.net/a9h9wbnv/

Comment: For a jQuery solution, I would propose an even simpler solution: `$('a').has('img').addClass('has-image')`; and then add a css class `has-image` which sets `background-color` on `hover` to `transparent` in the stylesheet, rather than within `hover` (which would be manipulating the `style` attribute each hover rather than just once :) Here's a example: http://jsfiddle.net/a9h9wbnv/2/

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely use a new class. Then, just use any decent text editor (like Notepad++) to find and replace:

FIND: `<a href="*"> <img`

REPLACE: `<a class="image-link" href="*"> <img`

And in your CSS:

```
a.image-link:hover {
 background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

So you want only the text hyperlink to have the hover?

```
If so, you can simply give the the 'Contact Us' a different class name or a specific ID. 

<a href="image.png">
    <img src="thumb.png" alt="" />
</a>

<a id = "contact" href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>


a {
    color: #1F497D;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#contact:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #1F497D;
}
```